# study the correlation of two time series with different length using R

Tags: r

I would like to study the correlation between two time series using R, one is observed data and the second in the outcome of numerical model. The problem is that the interval is not the same, so I have 3000 length for the observed data against around 40000 length for the numerical model. Therefore, I cannot use the related function in R as I receive an error says the length should be the same every time I run the code. how can I fix this?.

Comment: Well, you cannot do this. You need to allign the two timeseries so that they have identical time points. For example, if one is annual and the other is daily data, you can aggregate the daily data to annual data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.